# Webpack devserver client polling URL does not match Webpack devServer.public setting

Tags: javascript, nginx, webpack

Basic live test server running at: https://socket.syntapse.co.uk/wds1/. Does nothing more than load some bundles and console.log to test webpack client loading and live update function.

Problem: I am trying to set up webpack dev server to live-reload through an nginx reverse proxy. Though I have set what I believe are correct values in webpack.config.js the client html file is not using the correct "devServer.public" URL on polling and is omitting the path. I haven't changed the "devServer.sockPath" which defaults to "sockjs-node" nor the "devServer.inline" which defaults to true. Based on my configuration I expect the correct url for the wds server socket to be:

`https://socket.syntapse.co.uk/wds1/sockjs-node/info?t=1578494631898`

which does actually return valid json data as expected e.g.

```
{
"websocket": true,
"origins": [
"*:*"
],
"cookie_needed": false,
"entropy": 690102182
}
```

but the client page is repeatedly trying to poll on:

`https://socket.syntapse.co.uk/sockjs-node/info?t=1578494631898`

which as it omits the /wds1/ section of the path i define for "devServer.public" in webpack.config.js (full configuration below).

Problem summary: The client is not using the full "devServer.public" path defined in the webpack.config.js file as the root for its socket polling connection.

Configuration:

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name socket.syntapse.co.uk;
    # webpack socket
    location ^~ /wds1/sockjs-node/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3803/sockjs-node/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location ^~ /wds1/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3803/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

**webpack.conf.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.js',
        app: './src/app.js',
        print: './src/print.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 3802,
        public: 'https://socket.syntapse.co.uk/wds1/',
        disableHostCheck: true,
        overlay: {
            warnings: true,
            errors: true
        }        
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Development',
        }),
    ],
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-simple-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "simplest webpack-dev-server configuration",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode=development",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress"
  },
  ...,
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
  }
}
```

thanks

Comment: ive tried spltting the devServer.public to "http://socket.syntapse.co.uk" and devServer.publicPath to "/wds1/" but this returns an index of files in my root directory not the files specified in webpack.output.

Answer (score 1):

simple fix: need to include sockHost (only, no sockPort) the set correct client URL.

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.js',
        app: './src/app.js',
        print: './src/print.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 3802,
        sockHost: 'socket.syntapse.co.uk/wds1',
        public: 'socket.syntapse.co.uk/wds1/',
        disableHostCheck: true,
        overlay: {
            warnings: true,
            errors: true
        }        
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Development',
        }),
    ],
};
```